# How does Hadoop decide to distribute among buckets/nodes?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing, hadoop-partitioning

I am new to Map/Reduce and Hadoop framework.
I am running a Hadoop program on single machine (for trying it out).
I have n input files and I want some summary of words from those files.
I know map function returns key value pair, but how map is called? 
Once on each file or Once on each line of every file? Can I configure it?

Is it correct to assume, "reduce" is called for each key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hadoop MR framework,the job tracker creates a map task for each **InputSplit** as determined by the **InputFormat** specified by your job. Each **Inputsplit** assigned to map task is further processed by **RecordReader** to generate input key/value pairs for map function. The map function is called for each key/value pair that is generated by **RecordReader**.

For default **InputFormat** i.e **TextInputFormat** the input split will be single HDFS block which will be processed by single map task and **RecordReader** will process one line at a time within block and generate key/value pair where key is byte offset of starting of line in file and value is contents of line which will be passed to map function.

The number of reducers is dependent on job configuration by user and all key/value pairs with same key are grouped and will be sent to single reducer sorted by key but at same time single reducer can process multiple keys too.

For more details on **InputFormat** and customizing it, refer this YDN documentation:

**http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat**

Answer (score 2):

A map is called for one **InputSplit(or split in short)** and it is the duty of the **InputFormat**, you are using in your MR job, to crate these splits. It could be one line, multiple lines, one whole file and so on, based on the logic inside your InputFormat. For example, the default InputFormat, i.e **TextInputFormat** crates of splits which consist of **a single line**.

Yes you can configure it by altering the InputFormat you are using.

All the values corresponding to a particular key are clubbed together and multiple keys are partitioned into **partitions** and an entire partition goes to a reducer for further processing. So, all the values corresponding to a particular key get processed by a single reducer, but a single reducer can get multiple keys.